# PHP: representing an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sorry to bother with such a stupid question, but I'm teaching myself PHP and I'm having trouble with the basics.

I have the following:

```
$members
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: string = 19637
    theID: &string = 19637
    1: string = 4GM1  
    Code: &string = 4GM1  
    2: string = MARTIN
    Name: &string = MARTIN
```

How should I represent this in my code?

I'm doing:

```
$members = array( array( theID=> "19637", 
              Code => "4GM1",
              Name => "MARTIN"
   ));
```

But this shows in the debugger like:

```
$members 
: array = 
  0: array = 
    theID: string = 19637
    Code: string = 4GM1
    Name: string = MARTIN
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I wonder what the problem might be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$members = array(
  array(
         0  => '19637',
    'theID' => '19637',

         1  => '4GM1',
     'Code' => '4GM1',

         2  => 'MARTIN',
     'Name' => 'MARTIN'
  )
);
```